# What do you call the time period between notification of an event and the event?

Tags: time, terminology

I'm in the situation where I have an event, and I want to notify some people 15 minutes before that event happens (but it could be 30 minutes, or 1 day, or any amount of time).

What do you call that 15 minutes?

**UPDATE:** My specific case is for a program I'm writing. I have an event and I want to create a notification that happens X time before the event. I'm having trouble finding a name for that X time.

```
NOTIFICATION             TIME LAPSE                   EVENT
     |                       | (belongs to              |
     |                       |  notification)           |
     |<------------------------------------------------>|
```

I was trying to name it something like "Notification premure" or "Notification ahead-time", but none of them convince me, and I'm having troubles thinking of other alternatives. Any ideas?

Comment: **The calm before the storm**.

Comment: Alternatively: Nap time.

Comment: Outlook simply calls the notification a **Reminder**.  Create a new event on your calendar -- the UI has `Reminder: [15 minutes]`

Comment: @Jim: As a foreigner, I would prefer something like calmBeforeTheStorm in programming, it's very intuitive and I don't have to learn new words. +1

Comment: For the user interface or for a variable name? For the user interface it may well be clearer to have "reminder" and a drop-down box with "15m before", "1h before", etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You might call it the ***[interim](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interim)***.

Answer (score 21):

You might call it the *lead time* to the event.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right; the lead time would be the minimum possible time between deciding to do something and finishing it. An advance warning might be part of the lead time: see [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lead-time).

Comment: *Lead-up Period* might be better.

Answer (score 9):

You could call that period the *Alert Period* or *Notification Period* since it's the time between when the notification (or alert) occurs and the event that the notification notifies about.  I suppose if you want to make it sound more dramatic you could call it a *Countdown Period* (or maybe just *Countdown*) since you're counting down time to the event.

Comment: Thanks. Still, "Alert period" makes me think that the alarm will ring for 15 minutes non-stop. Do you know a way to call it that makes it sound more as a time difference than as a period of time?

Comment: @PabloVenturino: Hmmm... could you give an example sentence of how you'd like to use this term?

Comment: sure. I just updated the question to explain my problem better. Thanks!

Comment: How about *Notification Interval*?

Answer (score 6):

**LAST CALL** came to my mind, although it might not apply here.

Comment: +1 for the laugh ... one more round before we go, and make it a double.

Comment: I don't see how this could apply to this question.

Comment: @Marthaª just for fun :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a word for the notification itself, try "reminder", "alert", "notice", or "warning bell".

If you want a word for the time period itself (which I think is what you're asking), that could be a "pre-event period", "notice period", or "reminder period".  (I can't think of a single-word term.)

Comment: Thanks Monica. It doesn't need to be a single word, I'm just looking for something that's not a whole sentence.

Comment: +1 for "notice period" - it's the most obvious to me, whether talking about notice of a meeting or the ending of a contract.

Answer (score 4):

I think of this time period as the *reminder interval*.

From a user interface standpoint, it is worth noting that Google doesn't use any terminology for this time period when adding reminders to the calendar.  It's assumed that the reminders will be some period of time before the event so adding a reminder just prompts you for the type of reminder and the amount of time (10 mins default).

Maybe you could also check with ux.stackexchange.com to see what they recommend.

Answer (score 4):

A couple suggestions:

- `AdvanceNoticePeriod`
- `HeadsUpInterval`

Answer (score 4):

How about *notice period*?

In conversation, people may use just "notice", e.g. *one month's notice*, *two hours' notice*, etc

Answer (score 3):

I think the normal term for this would be *15 minutes notice*, or *two weeks notice*, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

I would refer to it as a `Notification Interval`

Answer (score 2):

Anticipation.  Positively or negatively.

Answer (score 2):

This would be derived from the term `an advance notification`, which is the correct term for what is *happening*. The actual time between the notification and the event would be called the `advance period`, which is also a legal term (used for instance in regards to loans).

Answer (score 0):

How about calling it the `grace time` of the event?

(On forced reboots, Windows gives you a short grace time to save and close everything you have open before the system shuts down for the reboot and forces everything to close.)

Comment: I've only ever heard it referred to as a *grace* ***period***, never *time*; and I don't think it answers the OP's question.